# Meeting probabilities of 2 individuals with random schedules

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two individuals make a schedule for a period of day **X** **hours**, setting up a total of **N meetings** (that is, while both individuals are equally likely to make a meeting, it is not guaranteed that Indv1 makes N/2 meetings) Each meeting lasts **L minutes** that begin at the start of each minute (no meeting begins at ex. 06:08:37).

Both individuals only are able to look up at the start of each minute (discrete, not continuous), to identify if the other is also in a meeting. **What is the probability they will "meet eyes"** - that they identify they are both in a meeting?

I saw a variation of this problem, but I am having trouble adapting the same line-of-thought for my problem formulation, especially for a non-continuous, discrete interval.

https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath124/kmath124.htm

Comment: It's not possible to have them independently set up meetings; the schedules are clearly *dependent* on each other, because the total number of meetings is fixed. You can say that their schedules are *conditionally* independent of each other given the number of meetings each will have. I think this detail, not the continuous vs discrete question (which is at worst a nuisance) will be what makes this problem meaningfully harder than the one you've linked.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery you are right. Let me rephrase.

Comment: I have asked a separate question, that is simpler version of this problem (counting exact overlaps, rather than partial overlaps). I will leave this question up as it is a different problem.